# If “Jesus is God”, what does it mean when He addresses the disciples as “brethren” in Matt. 28:10 and John 20:17?

Tags: john, matthew

1. Matt. 28:10: “..., “Do not be afraid, Go and tell My brethren to go to Galilee, and there they will see Me.”
2. John 20:17: “..., Do not cling to Me, for I have not yet ascended to My Father; but go to My brethren and say to them, I am ascending to My Father and your Father, and to My God and your God.”

Apostle Paul’s utterance of Heb. 2:10-13 also has a similar message to Matt. 28:10 & John 20:17.

Comment: For we can do nothing against the truth, but for the truth. (2Cor. 13:8)

Comment: See John 1:12-13.

Answer (score 3):

The Bible has many references to the saved being sons of God and brothers of Jesus.

- "… that he [Jesus] might be the firstborn among many brethren" — Romans 8:29
- "Wherefore thou art no more a servant, but a son; and if a son, then an heir of God through Christ." — Galatians 4:7
- "For in him we live, and move, and have our being; as certain also of your own poets have said, For we are also his offspring." — Acts 17:28
- "The Spirit itself beareth witness with our spirit, that we are the children of God:
  And if children, then heirs; heirs of God, and joint-heirs with Christ; if so be that we suffer with him, that we may be also glorified together." — Romans 8:16–17
- "And will be a Father unto you, and ye shall be my sons and daughters, saith the Lord Almighty." — 2Corinthians 6:18

Children are generally equal to their siblings, *and* equal to their parents.
Added to these relationships, there may be special privileges for the firstborn and special respect for the parents, but these are differences of rank, not of existence.

[Divinization (Christian) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divinization_(Christian)) provides a long list of Church Fathers that believed that man would become God.
For instance:

> In the second century, Irenaeus, bishop of Lyons (c. 130–202) said that God had "become what we are, that He might bring us to be even what He is Himself." He added:
>
> Do we cast blame on him [God] because we were not made gods from the beginning, but were at first created merely as men, and then later as gods? Although God has adopted this course out of his pure benevolence, that no one may charge him with discrimination or stinginess, he declares, "I have said, Ye are gods; and all of you are sons of the Most High."
> … For it was necessary at first that nature be exhibited, then after that what was mortal would be conquered and swallowed up in immortality.

Clement of Alexandria said:

> [T]he Word of God became man, that thou mayest learn from man how man may become God.

Augustine of Hippo said:

> If we have been made sons of God, we have also been made gods.

The Catechism of the Catholic Church says:

> The Word became flesh to make us "partakers of the divine nature": "For this is why the Word became man, and the Son of God became the Son of man: so that man, by entering into communion with the Word and thus receiving divine sonship, might become a son of God."
> "For the Son of God became man so that we might become God."
> "The only-begotten Son of God, wanting to make us sharers in his divinity, assumed our nature, so that he, made man, might make men gods."

Comment: The same church fathers that gave the church the trinity? If we start quoting them instead of the bible...

Comment: @user48152, agreed.  The non-biblical quotations were intended to show that this is not a recent concept or interpretation (albeit one that is seldom taught in churches).

Comment: yes, and why doesn't the bible teach it? Biblically, b/c it isn't true - like the other stuff the CF's taught. Like Jesus being God.

Comment: It’s the first thing to know, ‘that no prophecy of Scripture is of ANY private interpretation.” (2Peter 1:20). Any thing NOT found in the Bible is bound to controversy and division.

Comment: @user48152 - referencing contemporary and near-contemporary sources is a valid and useful hermeneutical tool. Any one of us could quote a passage or group of passages and make them say whatever we want them to say (this is commonly known as the 'Pearls on a string' approach). Demonstrating the interpretations of near-contemporary witnesses is often a useful way of narrowing down interpretations which reflect the contexts of the original recipients.

Answer (score 3):

**If “Jesus is God”, what does it mean when He addresses the disciples as “brethren” in**

Matt. 28:10 and John 20:17?

> Matt. 28:10: “..., “Do not be afraid, Go and tell My brethren to go to
> Galilee, and there they will see Me.

My brethren/brothers:

Here Jesus calls his disciples “brothers” because of the spiritual relationship they enjoy. Even after he was raised from the dead to the spirit realm, Jesus called his followers “my brothers.” (Matthew 28:10) Were they brothers of Almighty God? Of course not! But through their faith in Christ,​they too became sons of the one Father.

Galatians 3:26  (NET Bible)

> 26 For in Christ Jesus you are all sons of God through faith.[a]

All those led by  God's spirit are children of God—heirs of God and co-heirs with Christ. The brothers of Christ are called the sons of God

Romans 8:14, 16-17  (NIV)

> 14 For those who are led by the Spirit of God are the children of God.
> 16 The Spirit himself testifies with our spirit that we are God’s
> children. 17 Now if we are children, then we are heirs—heirs of God
> and co-heirs with Christ, if indeed we share in his sufferings in
> order that we may also share in his glory.

**Conclusion:**

Jesus never claims to be God, he said that the true worshipers are those that do the will of his Father and not his: " For whoever does the will of My Father who is in heaven, he is My brother, and sister, and mother.”(Matt. 12:50 NASB).

Further, all descendants of the imperfect Adam were slaves to sin, so they could not be considered sons of God. But thanks to Jesus’ ransom sacrifice, God can free them from slavery to sin and adopt them as his sons, **making them joint-heirs with Christ.** (Romans  8:14-17,  Galatians  4:1-7)

Romans 8:14-17   NASB

> 14 For all who are being led by the Spirit of God, these are sons and
> daughters of God. 15 For you have not received a spirit of slavery
> leading to fear again, but you have received a spirit of adoption as
> sons and daughters by which we cry out, “Abba! Father!” 16 The Spirit
> Himself testifies with our spirit that we are children of God, 17 and
> if **children,** heirs also, **heirs of God and fellow heirs with Christ**, if
> indeed we suffer with Him so that we may also be glorified with Him.

Comment: Maybe just me, but I don't think you got to the answer - not succinctly anyway - perhaps a summary is in order.

Comment: user48152 Comment noted and appreciated,a summary is in orded tks

Comment: That's better! I thought of J calling the Pharisees 'sons of the devil' ie - NOT sons of God.

Answer (score 0):

One of the great Biblical atonement metaphors is that of reconciliation.  In 2 Cor 5:18, 19 we find that Christ reconciled the world to Himself by “not counting our sins against us”.  Rom 5:10, 11 teaches that sinners were reconciled to God by Christ’s death.  Further, a comparison with v9 shows that justification and reconciliation are used in parallel.

This is all summed up in the what is known as the great divine exchange of 2 Cor 5:21 -

> God made Him who knew no sin to be sin on our behalf, so that in Him
> we might become the righteousness of God.

That is, Christ so identified with us that he took responsibility of our sin!

This metaphor of family reconciliation is based on two parallel ideas of Hebrew idiom:

1. Jesus is our brother (Heb 2:11-13, Ps 22:22, Isa 8:17, 18, Matt 12:48, 49, John 20:17, Rom 8:29)
2. sin separates us from Jesus our brother (Isa 59:2, Gal 5:4, Eph 2:12, Ps 22:1, Eze 14:5, Jer 6:8).

Thus, as our beloved brother, Jesus takes responsibility for the family reconciliation, and reconciles us to God by His sacrificial death.

This is further reinforced by forgiven sinners being called "children of God", 1 John 3:1-3, 10, 5:2, John 11:52, Rom 8:16, 14, 9:8, Gal 3:26, Matt 5:9, Phil 2:15, Heb 2:13, etc.  As children of God we can call the Son of God our brother.

**Supplementary note**: The fact that Jesus is called the "Son of God" does not make Him any less God because He is called "the God" (ho theos) in places like Matt 1:23, John 20:28, and equal to the Father in other places such as John 1:18, 5:17, 18, 23, 10:30, Phil 2:5-8, 1 Tim 3:16, Titus 2;13, Heb 1:8, 9, 2 Peter 1:1, Isa 9:6, 7, etc.

Comment: 'Took responsibility for our sin'. That's … false! He took the penalty for our sin. Which, perhaps, is what you intended...? He certainly is not 'responsible' for our sin - nor did God ask him to take it. The devil is the one held responsible, and God is responsible to fix what it has caused. The verse you quoted is debatable re. the meaning of, 'to be sin ', and can readily be read with other texts, 'he became the offering for sin'.

Comment: oh and, you have mis quoted 2 Cor 5:18 - "Christ reconciled the world to Himself ". rather it reads, *God*, who reconciled us to himself *through* Christ. Fine example of trying to work out how God can reconcile us to Himself through himself. That's not what it says.

Comment: @user48152 - I read 2 Cor 5:21 as it reads - He "who knew no sin to be sin on our behalf" - that is certainly taking responsibility for our sin.  If God did not take responsibility for our sin, we certainly could not have because that would mean we die for our own sins.  But this is not the place to debate.

Answer (score -1):

There are many instances throughout the bible in which  Jesus' divinity is called into question. To clarify, Jesus is the Father, the Son and the Holy Spirit. During his earthly walk, Jesus had relatives-- parents, brothers, sisters, cousins, friends, etc. He also  takes meaning of family to another level when he states, "For whoever does the will of my Father in heaven is my brother and sister and mother."(Matthew 12:50) Therefore it is appropriate and an honor for Jesus to refer to his followers as  "brethren."
So whether we read of Jesus praying to the Father or referring to his followers as brethren, these scriptures still hold true:

1Tim 3:16 And without controversy great is the mystery of godliness: God was manifest in the flesh, justified in the Spirit, seen of angels, preached unto the Gentiles, believed on in the world, received up into glory.

1John 5:7 For there are three that bear record in heaven, the Father, the Word, and the Holy Ghost: and these three are one.8 And there are three that bear witness in earth, the Spirit, and the water, and the blood: and these three agree in one.

Titus 2:13   Looking for that blessed hope, and the glorious appearing of the great God and our Savior Jesus Christ.

1John 5:20 And we know that the Son of God is come, and hath given us an understanding, that we may know him that is true, and we are in him that is true, even in his Son Jesus Christ. This is the true God, and eternal life.

John 1:1-3  In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.2The same was in the beginning with God.3All things were made by him; and without him was not any thing made that was made.

John 1:14 And the Word was made flesh, and dwelt among us, (and we beheld his glory, the glory as of the only begotten of the Father,) full of grace and truth.

Comment: Note that part of 1John 5:7, known as the [Johannine Comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannine_Comma), is generally considered to be an addition, not in the original scriptures. [1 John 5:7 - Bible Gateway](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/1%20John%205:7) gives a list of many English translations, most of which omit the added material.

Comment: The Bible does not teach that Jesus is the Father. He is the son of God.

Comment: Jesus Himself (Self-Witness) said God is “My Father” almost 55 times according to Matthew, Luke and John as follows:

Matt. 7:21; 10:32; 10:33; 11:27; 12:50; 15:13; 16:17; 18:10; 18:19; 18:35; 20:23; 24:36; 25:34; 26:39; 26:42; 26:53 (16 times);
Luke 2:49; 10:22; 22:29; 22:42; 24:49 (5 times);
John 2:16; 5:17; 5:43; 6:32; 6:65; 8:19; 8:28; 8:38; 8:49; 8:54; 10:17; 10:18; 10:25; 10:29; 10:30; 10:32; 10:37; 12:26; 14:2; 14:7; 14:12; 14:20; 14:21; 14:23; 14:28; 15:1; 15:8; 15:10; 15:15; 15:23; 15:24; 16:10; 18:11; 20:17 (34 times).

Comment: So, the answer to the question is that ‘Jesus is the ONLY begotten Son of God (John 1:18; Matt. 3:17; 12:18; 17:5; Mark 1:11; 9:7), and believers become the children of God and therefore privileged to be ‘brethren’ of Jesus Christ.

Comment: All scripture must agree. Such as in the case of the Trinity. At first glance, scriptures tend to rival each other, sparking concerns of controversy. The only existing controversy is attributed to that of the reader who refuses to allow the mystery of godliness to  operate according to God's own will. 
1Timothy 3:16 “And without controversy great is the mystery of godliness: God was manifest in the flesh,….”
Colossians 2:9 “For in him dwelleth all the fullness of the Godhead bodily.